# What does it mean to have red bars in battery usage graph even while charging?

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

I got a new iPhone (12 mini) this week and its battery usage graph does something that my previous iPhone (SE) didn't.

The old iPhone only showed red bars when battery was really low. The new one shows red bars randomly spread, even while charging. What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: For the record, this behavior eventually resolved on its own. Never found out what it means or what could be the cause.